# Express the given Fractions as Continued Fractions

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

Using only the numbers, $1$, $2$, $12$.

No concatenations allowed.

Only permitted signs are plus and division.

Brackets are not needed.

Expressions should be as concise as possible.

Typical example:

[image]

Fill in the right hand side for each of the three following cases:

A.   $136/11$ =

B.   $235/19$=

C.  $4131/334$=

Comment: The title says "continued fractions", the question says "plus and division". The first of those is a stricter condition than the second. E.g., the trivial solutions that look like $\frac{1+1+\cdots+1}{1+1+\cdots+1}$ satisfy the second but not the first. What's the actual requirement?

Comment: Typical continued fractions involve plus, minus, division..I will post an example.

Comment: I know what a continued fraction is. The question is whether, as the title suggests, you literally mean that you want a continued fraction; or whether, as the question text suggests, you are content with any expression built out of +,-,/. (If the former then I don't even understand why you need to specify +-/ only. If the latter then I don't understand why continued fractions are in the title.)

Comment: It looks as if the answer is that you did mean continued fractions, without even permitting "generalized continued fractions" where the numerator isn't 1. If so, then I don't see how there's the slightest element of puzzliness to the question. There is a standard, simple, obvious algorithm for computing continued fractions, and the only degree of freedom left to the solver is how to write each coefficient as a sum of 1s, 2s and 12s, and since each of those numbers divides the next there's also an obvious way to optimize _that_. Am I missing something?

Comment: If I don’t restrict the signs, all kinds of answers can be given without uniqueness..of course algos can be written..I want the solvers to figure out the way of writing the expression with minimal ambiguities. .Recently, I have been accused of being not specific to the intent of the puzzles..that’s why I tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: This series was developed to minimize year..month discrepancies over longer period of years...as we go to higher fractions further and further..leads to lower and lower discrepancies.

Comment: It's not a matter of "algos can be written". It's that there's already an algorithm for it that's well known and easy to figure out even if you haven't seen it before. I agree that being specific is good, but some highly-specific questions are just too routine to make good puzzles.

Comment: Agreed..........

Comment: I think the concern here is that a “puzzle” solved by mechanical application of a well understood algorithm/process isn’t really a puzzle. See the comments [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50888235) as well as [this answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2787) to a very relevant question on our Meta, which feels exactly like this question. Compare the guidance [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{136}{11}$

> $12 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + 2}}}$

$\frac{235}{19}$

> $12 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2}}}}$

$\frac{4131}{334}$

> $12 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{12+2+2+1}}}}}}$

Comment: Yes..this is the form I am expecting for the other 2 also as shown in the example

Comment: Check the last 2..don’t add up right

Comment: Last 1 ok..checking 2nd one..

Comment: All 3 ok..got all